# Extended ubuntu-server VM's memory. Still not enough available size

Tags: server, partitioning, 20.04, memory-usage, vmware-workstation

I recently installed an Ubuntu-server (20.04) on VM initially giving it only 10Gb RAM. Soon enough, I noticed that the program I need to install (Gluu-server) requires at least 40Gb. Hence, I proceeded to power off the VM and extend the memory to 70Gb.

Running `lsblk` indeed shows that `sda` partition is 70Gb.  But `sda3` on which the actual OS is installed has only 9Gb of free space.

```
user@ubuntuserver:/$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                         2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
loop0                       7:0    0 30.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9279
loop1                       7:1    0   55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop2                       7:2    0 70.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16922
loop3                       7:3    0 55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop4                       7:4    0 29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop5                       7:5    0 71.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16099
sda                         8:0    0   70G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0    9G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    9G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
sr1                        11:1    1 1024M  0 rom
```

I tried to install gluu server and I get this message:

```
root@localhost:/install/community-edition-setup# ./setup.py
Detected OS ubuntu 20
Warning: Available free disk space was determined to be 2.9 GB. This is less than the required disk space of 40 GB.
```

I am kinda confused. Why is the "available free disk space determined to be only 2.9 GB"? Is this a partitioning issue and how can I fix that?

Comment: Your root partition is sda3 and it is using lvm (Logical Volume Management). So far you have not changed its size. What you have changed is the size of the device sda3 lives on, that's sda. sda will have a load of unallocated space. You need to do two things. The first is to expand sda3 into the unallocated space you have provided. The second is to make use of that additional space. This is a good reference https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/

Comment: You should post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root partition is sda3 and it is using lvm (Logical Volume Management). So far you have not changed its size. What you have changed is the size of the device sda3 lives on, that's sda. sda will have a load of unallocated space. You need to do two things.

1. The first is to expand sda3 into the unallocated space you have provided.
2. The second is to make use of that additional space.

This is a good reference https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/